# How can I validate __slots__ in child classes?

Tags: python, class, slots

From the [python docs 3.3.2.4.1](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots), it says  "`__slots__` declared in parents are available in child classes. However, child subclasses will get a `__dict__` and `__weakref__` unless they also define `__slots__` (which should only contain names of any additional slots)."

However, while I was testing this as below:

```
class A(object):
    __slots__ = ('a')

class B(A):
    __slots__ = ('b')

b = B()
B.z = 'z'
B.a = 'a'
print(B.z) #z
print(B.a) #a
print(B.__dict__) #{'__module__': '__main__', '__slots__': ('b',), 'b': <member 'b' of 'B' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'z': 'z', 'a': 'a'}
```

Neither `B.z` nor `B.__dict__` throws exception, the code manages to output.

I am confused why the `__slots__ = ('b')` in `Class B` doesn't validate. Theoretically, it should throw an exception at B.z because the keys in slots don't contain it.

Could you please help to explain this strange point? And if possible, could you please help to provide the right usage method of slots in child classes?

By the way, my python version is 3.9.7

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The `__slots__` should be a tuple there, but you don't actually have a tuple, you have a string. Try doing `__slots__ = ("a",)`.

Also, the slots apply to instances, not classes. You are assigning the attribute to the class object. Try the following. The instances work as expected.

```py
a = A()
a.a = "a"
# a.b = "b"  # fails

b = B()
b.b = "b"
b.a = 'a'
# b.z = 'z'  # fails
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your help! And now I've known why I see some example uses __slots__ = ('a',)instead of ('a'). It's true it apply to instances so I should use b instead of the class B! Thank you again for your kindly help!!